# How to export Google Slide as png after importing image to it from Google Form - Apps Script Image from Form to Slide and export to png

Tags: google-apps-script, png, google-slides

Hello i try to make simple template file for mixing toegether two images.
One is as overlay of slide and second one come from Google Form as background.

Problem is that i don't have any knowledge about this code.
I stuck at this point and i cant combine this two piece of code.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //open the template presentation by ID
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1bGKJ027bnUCgSpQrunXXBZCgFNXZHtF2ZnsaWHLh8B4');
  //create a copy of the template, we don't wanna mess up the template presentation
  var newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy();
  
  //open the presentation for editing
  var openSlide = SlidesApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());

  //get the responses triggered by On Form Submit
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  
  //find the text in the presentation and replace it with the Form response
  //items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the Form
  //and it is the "Title"
  //openSlide.replaceAllText('{Title}', items[0].getResponse());
  //items[1].getResponse() is the second and it is the date
  //openSlide.replaceAllText('{Text}', items[1].getResponse());

  //You can add as much as you have and change them in the Template Doc like this
  //openSlide.replaceAllText('{number}', items[2].getResponse());
  //openSlide.replaceAllText('{choice}', items[3].getResponse());
  //and so on...
  
var image = items[0].getResponse();
openSlide.getSlides().forEach(s => {
  s.getShapes().forEach(e => {
    if (e.getText().asString().trim() == '{{image1}}') {
      e.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(Array.isArray(image) ? image[0] : image).getBlob());
    }
  })
});

  //Save and Close the open document
  DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId()).setName(items[0].getResponse());
 
}
// this is code for making PNG file from slide, it work like a charm when its running in simple slide file with slide id pasted  in presentationId (below) but i cant figure it out how to present the id of new (above) just created slide to code below. folderId is easy i think. But problem is with this presentationId 

var folderId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"//เปลี่ยน ไอดีโฟลเดอร์เป็นของท่านเอง
var presentationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"//เปลี่ยน ไอดี Slide เป็นของท่านเอง

function convertToPNG() {
  var slideId = 'p';
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + presentationId +
    '/export/png?id=' + presentationId + '&pageid=' + slideId; 
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var image = response.getAs(MimeType.PNG);
  image.setName("png-"+Math.random().toFixed(2));
  //image.setName(DriveApp.getFileById(presentationId).getName());
  var img = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(image).getUrl()
  Logger.log(img)

}
```

I try my best to combine these two codes but nothing works for me (because I have zero knowledge of this scripting language)

Can someone try to give me a hint on how to tell the second part of the code to know from what SlideId should make a png file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
// Open the template presentation by ID
var templateDoc = 
SlidesApp.openById('1bGKJ027bnUCgSpQrunXXBZCgFNXZHtF2ZnsaWHLh8B4');
// Create a copy of the template, we don't want to mess up the template 


  presentation
  var newTempFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDoc.getId()).makeCopy();

  // Open the new presentation for editing
  var newSlide = SlidesApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());

  // Get the responses triggered by on form submit
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();

  // Find the text in the presentation and replace it with the form 
response
  // Items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the form and it is 
the "Title"
  // OpenSlide.replaceAllText('{Title}', items[0].getResponse());
  // Items[1].getResponse() is the second and it is the date
  // OpenSlide.replaceAllText('{Text}', items[1].getResponse());

  // You can add as much as you have and change them in the template doc 
like this
  // OpenSlide.replaceAllText('{number}', items[2].getResponse());
  // OpenSlide.replaceAllText('{choice}', items[3].getResponse());
  // And so on...
  
  var image = items[0].getResponse();
  newSlide.getSlides().forEach(s => {
    s.getShapes().forEach(e => {
      if (e.getText().asString().trim() == '{{image1}}') {
        e.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(Array.isArray(image) ? 
image[0] : image).getBlob());
      }
    })
  });
  
  // Save and close the new document
  newSlide.saveAndClose();

  // Save the new slide as a PDF
  var newSlideFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId());
  var pdfBlob = newSlideFile.getAs('application/pdf');
  var pdfName = items[0].getResponse() + '.pdf';
  var folder = 
DriveApp.getFolderById('1lEP4qtXs6fITXS9GKeaYKLfbRONgbuOQ');
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(pdfName));

   
   var folderId = "10XCnKfhk4_5agWCYxWHGCO6wwxWSG7Y9"
   // Save the new slide as a PNG file
  var slideId = newSlide.getSlides()[0].getObjectId();
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + newSlide.getId() 
+ '/export/png?id=' + newSlide.getId() + '&pageid=' + slideId; 
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var image = response.getAs(MimeType.PNG);
  image.setName("png-"+Math.random().toFixed(2));
  //image.setName(DriveApp.getFileById(presentationId).getName());
  var img = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(image).getUrl()
  Logger.log(img)

}
```